# Showing existence of modular function

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, modular-forms

I am studying Mock Modular forms in the book Harmonic Maass Forms and Mock Modular Forms: Theory and Applications and i have problems with a theorem.

In Theorem 6.4 it says

If $Z_E^+ $ has poles in $\mathbb{H}$ then there is a canonical modular function $M_E$ on $\Gamma_0(N_E)$ which has algebraic coefficients for which $Z_E^+ - M_E$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{H}$.

$Z_E(\tau)$ is the modified Weierstrass $\zeta$-Function evaluated for the Eichler integral $\mathcal{E}_E(\tau)$.

The book provides an explanation with saying it follows from using standard algebraic facts for modular functions but i fail to understand it. So i would be glad if someone could elaborate on this more. Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})= \ \ \bigcup_{l=1}^L \gamma_j \Gamma_0(N)$ where $\gamma_1(z) = z$ then 
$\frac{\prod_{l=2}^L (j(Nz)-j(N \gamma_l(a)))}{j(z)-j(a)} \in \mathbb{C}(X_0(N))$ and for most $a$ it has a unique simple pole at $\Gamma_0(N) a$ on the upper half-plane.

Comment: @reuns hmm thank you but i still have trouble understanding it. Would you please elaborate it more if you got the time

Comment: It is up to you to elaborate, I don't know what you mean with $Z_E^+$ and algebraic coefficients, I showed that it is not hard to construct a modular function with prescribed poles on $\mathbb{H}$.